# How to Give Serial No In html Table MVC? use css or Jquery

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a Mvc Table it looks like this:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SL NO
            </th>
            <th>Designation Name
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> 
//Here I want Serial No here [I used Paging] 
                </td>
                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.desigantionName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled p-x-2">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.desigantionId }) </div>
                    <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled p-x-2">@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.desigantionId }) </div>
                    <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled p-x-2">@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.desigantionId })</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

above code first column  I want serial no I use sl no use css but problem is when go to next page index sl no resart upto 1 
each pager I used 5 rows I need to start 2nd page index sl no upto 6

Comment: How do you retrieve your model? You must be aware of the offset when getting the data for the model. Can you add some index in your model?

Comment: Your question barely makes sense. How can you possibly use jQuery or CSS to render out a serial number? Unless you mean 'index' or you just want a sequential number on each item, like `1,2,3,4,<new page> 5,6,7,8` (in which case as @derpirscher says, you must know the offset)?


If you do mean serial number, it has to be a property of the item that you're rendering, it needs to be unique, so you can't just generate it out of thin air on the front end, and it doesn't have anything to do with paging. Why can't you just render `item.serialNumber` or whatever that property is called?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,if you want to print the serial no of the data in Model.`pagesize` and `pageNum` should be set according to the current page number and its size

```
             <tbody>

                 @{ int i = 0; }                       
                   @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td> 
                                <label>pageSize * (pageNum - 1) +  @i</label>  //your serial no
                                 @{ i++; }     
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.desigantionName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled p-x-2">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.desigantionId }) </div>
                                <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled p-x-2">@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.desigantionId }) </div>
                                <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled p-x-2">@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.desigantionId })</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody
```

Comment: That will only work for the first page. The op explicitely said, he uses pagination and wants the index on the second page to start with, for instance, 5. your approach will always print 0, 1, ...